# Get attributes of selected text in JTextPane

Tags: java, attributes, selection, jtextpane, caret

I'm trying to find out how to get the attributes of some selected text in JTextPane.
I found that the best solution is to do it with getInputAttributes() and CaretListener, but I have some issues with this implementation.

Here's my solution showing the attributes of the text on the last position of the caret, but not on the actual position of the caret. What am I doing wrong? Please.

[image]

Here is my SSCCE:

```
public class Testovani{
static JTextPane pane;
static JLabel label;

public static void main(String[] args) throws BadLocationException {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(350, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    
    pane = new JTextPane();
    label = new JLabel();
    pane.addCaretListener(new SelectionListener());
    
    MutableAttributeSet attrs = new SimpleAttributeSet();
    StyleConstants.setBold(attrs, true);
    pane.getDocument().insertString(0, "\n", null);
    pane.getDocument().insertString(0, "This is first row non bold", null);
    pane.getDocument().insertString(0, "\n", null);
    pane.getDocument().insertString(0, "This is second row bold", attrs);
    pane.getDocument().insertString(0, "\n", null);
    pane.getDocument().insertString(0, "This is third row bold", attrs);
    pane.getDocument().insertString(0, "\n", null);
    
    frame.add(pane);
    frame.add(label, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private static class SelectionListener implements CaretListener{
    @Override
    public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent e) {
        AttributeSet attrs =((StyledEditorKit)pane.getEditorKit()).getInputAttributes();
        label.setText("Is bold: " + String.valueOf(StyleConstants.isBold(attrs)));
    }   
}}
```

And I have two bonus questions. Is this approach functional for selection or just for the position of caret? And what returns, if there is a selection of text where one part is bold and second part is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually attributes of selection is complicated question and need your understanding of business requirements.

Suppose a fragment of text is selected and you need the selection font size. But 
the fragment has 3 different pieces of text with 3 different sizes.

Selection start position is placed in the mid of 10pt text, then piece of text with 12pt size and selection ends in the mid of 14pt size fragment.

What size do you expect? 10, 12, 14 or (multiple)?

The simplest approach is to use inputAttributes.

By default the attributes are copied from caret position but of course you can add a caret listener and on each update check and fill the input attributes as you need according to your business logic (processing the multiple text fragments with different attributes).

UPDATE:
Try to wrap the `AttributeSet attrs =((StyledEditorKit)pane.getEditorKit()).getInputAttributes();` in SwingUtilities.invokeLater() call

Comment: Definitely useful answer, I will use it later. But first, I need to know, why method getInputAttributes() in my CaretListener returns attributes of previous caret position.

Comment: This is because it is usually the expected behaviour : if you place your caret after a bold text, you generally expect your input to be bold as well

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. Update in StanislavL answer is solution of my problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is no expected behaviour for getting the attributes of a selection, simply because a selection can have character elements with each different attributes.

You have to understand that there is a difference between `getInputAttributes` which returns the attributes that the textPane calculated the best for a next input, and `getCharacterAttributes` that returns the attributes of the current caret position. In the case of a selection, the caret is the position where you ended the selection. It can be the `getSelectionStart` or `getSelectionEnd` given if you selected text from left to right or from right to left.

Anyway, what I advice you is to get the StyledDocument of your JTextPane, and then iterate through the character elements from `getSelectionStart` to `getSelectionEnd` :

```
for(int i=jtp.getSelectionStart(); i<jtp.getSelectionEnd(); i++) {
    AttributeSet set = jtp.getStyledDocument().getCharacterElement(i).getAttributes();
    //here, combine, analyse, do whatever you like with your AttributeSet
    //You can use StyleConstants.xxx to analyse the attributes
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm already using this for selected text. But if there is no selection, it not works properly in some special cases. If there is no selection, I want attributes which will be used for text, what will be write. I expected, that is the return of method getInputAttributes() and it seems to be. But it gives me attributes of last caret position. Not previous character attributes, but previous caret position anywhere in document. (Look at the picture.) It is not expected behavior, I hope. Then I must doing something wrong. Do you know what? Please.

Comment: This probably means that your caretListener is called before the input style is updated. Anyway, I always had trouble with the default style calculation of JTextPane, so I ended up doing my own. What you can do is to stop relaying on inputAttributes, and use or the attributes of the character before selectionStart (it works even with no selection), or a default Style if the caret is just after a new line (\n) or at the start of document

Answer (score 0):

I used @Sharcoux 's solution with one change: I made sure that there there was always at least one character to iterate over.  When there's no selection, `getSelectionStart() == getSelectionEnd()`. For this reason I would make the slight change of:

```
int iStart = jtp.getSelectionStart();
int iEnd = jtp.getSelectionEnd();
if(iStart > 0) iStart--;
else if(iEnd < jtp.getDocument().getEndPosition().getOffset()) iEnd++;
for(int i = iStart; i < iEnd; i++) {
    AttributeSet set = jtp.getStyledDocument().getCharacterElement(i).getAttributes();
    //here, combine, analyse, do whatever you like with your AttributeSet
    //You can use StyleConstants.xxx to analyse the attributes
}
```

The only instance in which this changes nothing is when the document is completely empty, in which case `getInputAttributes` should work fine.